# Fact Table Partitioning?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, etl, data-warehouse, partitioning

I have a 10 gb fact table. I have a claim date that I would like to partition on. I have a clustered index on Identity ID . Do I need to change my index to partition horizontally ? Do I need to create a primary index on both the identity ID as well as on the date ?

Comment: Did you get an error when you tried to create the partitioning function?

Comment: No, we are stil in the design phase. Basically, would like to know what should be indexed and what should not be indexed for horizontal partitioning ?